# Creating view with additional column based on multiple condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, between

I've been trying to sort out some data from my current job. I need to create additional column with shift number that depends on the product creation hour. The table looks like this:

```
product_id    creation_time         warehouse_name
  varchar       timestamp                varchar
    1      2016-03-29 08:30:45            11
    2      2016-03-15 14:15:10            9
    3      2016-03-14 05:40:45            11
```

Now I need to add a column with a shift number that's based on the hours - 06:00:00 - 14:00:00 shift 1, 14:00:00-22:00:00 shift 2 and 22:00:00-06:00:00 shift 3. I'm quite new when it comes to sql, I know how to add a column via AS, but I don't know how to fill the column with correct data based on the condition that's based on the timestamps. We're using postgres database via pgadmin.I tried something like:

```
 SELECT creation_time, product_id, warehouse_name
 FROM products WHERE creation_time BETWEEN LIKE '%06:00:00' AND '%14:00:00';
```

but I'm lost at how to insert the condition data into a new column named shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't compare timestamp values using `LIKE`. To select the rows with a time between 06:00 and 14:00 cast the timestamp to a `time` and compare that:

```
SELECT creation_time, product_id, warehouse_name
FROM products 
WHERE creation_time::time BETWEEN time '06:00:00' AND time '14:00:00';
```

The same "trick" can be used to create the shift column:

```
SELECT creation_time, product_id, warehouse_name, 
       case 
         when creation_time::time between time '06:00:00' AND time '14:00:00' then 1
         when creation_time::time BETWEEN time '14:00:01' AND time '22:00:00' then 2
         else 3
       end as shift_number
FROM products;
```

The `between` operator includes both values that's why the second check starts 1 second after 14:00

`time '06:00:00'` specifies a time literal (constant). For more details on how to specify time (or timestamp) values, please see the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot about casting the timestamp... Anyway your answer solves my problem. Thanks again.